# systemd-journald is not persisting logs on system running Docker

Tags: systemd, logs, journalctl, persistence

Every hour or so systemd-journald is deleting any logs older than about an hour instead of persisting them to /var/log/journal/. I have set storage=persistent in journal.conf. Whenever the logs rotate they are not being flushed.

systemd-journald override to show debug logs in dmesg:

```
pi@######:/etc/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service.d$ cat override.conf
[Service]
Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

These are the logs that appear in dmesg when deletion happens :

```
[Tue Jun 14 11:13:33 2022] systemd-journald[2020]: /run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024/system.journal: Journal header limits reached or header out-of-date, rotating.
[Tue Jun 14 11:13:33 2022] systemd-journald[2020]: Rotating...
[Tue Jun 14 11:13:33 2022] systemd-journald[2020]: Reserving 8448 entries in hash table.
[Tue Jun 14 11:13:33 2022] systemd-journald[2020]: Vacuuming...
[Tue Jun 14 11:13:33 2022] systemd-journald[2020]: Deleted archived journal /run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024/system@d30583b2cbf04d2aab3e5927a175ef5e-0000000000065a39-0005e163dbe0ff99.journal (4.6M).
[Tue Jun 14 11:13:33 2022] systemd-journald[2020]: Vacuuming done, freed 4.6M of archived journals from /run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024.
```

One major thing I don't understand is why it shows in journalctl that the journal has stopped when I'm sending the command to journalctl? you can see by the date below that it stopped and never started again. I'm guessing this is why the logs aren't being flushed?

systemd-journald logs:

```
pi@#######:~$ date
Wed Jun 15 11:06:27 SAST 2022
pi@#######:~$ sudo journalctl -u systemd-journald | cat
-- Logs begin at Mon 2022-01-10 06:56:38 SAST, end at Wed 2022-06-15 11:06:34 SAST. --
Jan 10 06:56:39 ####### systemd-journald[2019]: Journal started
Jan 10 06:56:39 ####### systemd-journald[2019]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 4.6M, max 37.1M, 32.4M free.
-- Reboot --
Jan 10 06:56:39 ####### systemd-journald[2011]: Journal started
Jan 10 06:56:39 ####### systemd-journald[2011]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 4.6M, max 37.1M, 32.4M free.
Jan 10 06:56:39 ####### systemd-journald[2011]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 4.6M, max 37.1M, 32.4M free.
-- Reboot --
Jan 10 06:56:39 ####### systemd-journald[2019]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 4.6M, max 37.1M, 32.4M free.
Jun 13 12:16:53 ####### systemd-journald[2019]: Journal stopped
Jun 13 12:16:53 ####### systemd-journald[7765]: Journal started
Jun 13 12:16:53 ####### systemd-journald[7765]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 18.5M, max 37.1M, 18.5M free.
Jun 13 12:16:53 ####### systemd-journald[7765]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024 is 455.515ms for 8948 entries.
Jun 13 12:16:53 ####### systemd-journald[7765]: System Journal (/var/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 24.0M, max 900.0M, 876.0M free.
Jun 13 12:19:39 ####### systemd-journald[7765]: Journal stopped
Jun 13 12:19:39 ####### systemd-journald[8468]: Journal started
Jun 13 12:19:39 ####### systemd-journald[8468]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 4.6M, max 37.1M, 32.4M free.
Jun 13 12:19:39 ####### systemd-journald[8468]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024 is 4.480ms for 15 entries.
Jun 13 12:19:39 ####### systemd-journald[8468]: System Journal (/var/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 32.0M, max 900.0M, 867.9M free.
Jun 13 12:19:49 ####### systemd-journald[8468]: Journal stopped
Jun 13 12:19:49 ####### systemd-journald[8648]: Journal started
Jun 13 12:19:49 ####### systemd-journald[8648]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 4.6M, max 37.1M, 32.4M free.
Jun 13 12:19:49 ####### systemd-journald[8648]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024 is 6.845ms for 54 entries.
Jun 13 12:19:49 ####### systemd-journald[8648]: System Journal (/var/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 32.0M, max 900.0M, 867.9M free.
Jun 13 12:22:28 ####### systemd-journald[8648]: Journal stopped
-- Reboot --
Jan 10 06:56:39 ####### systemd-journald[2014]: Journal started
Jan 10 06:56:39 ####### systemd-journald[2014]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 4.6M, max 37.1M, 32.4M free.
Jan 10 06:56:39 ####### systemd-journald[2014]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 4.6M, max 37.1M, 32.4M free.
Jun 13 15:57:22 ####### systemd-journald[2014]: Journal stopped
Jun 13 15:57:22 ####### systemd-journald[6463]: Journal started
Jun 13 15:57:22 ####### systemd-journald[6463]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 27.8M, max 37.1M, 9.2M free.
Jun 13 15:57:22 ####### systemd-journald[6463]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024 is 2.085184s for 16277 entries.
Jun 13 15:57:22 ####### systemd-journald[6463]: System Journal (/var/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 48.0M, max 900.0M, 851.9M free.
Jun 13 15:57:42 ####### systemd-journald[6463]: Journal stopped
Jun 13 15:57:42 ####### systemd-journald[6532]: Journal started
Jun 13 15:57:42 ####### systemd-journald[6532]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 4.6M, max 37.1M, 32.4M free.
Jun 13 15:57:42 ####### systemd-journald[6532]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024 is 5.834ms for 19 entries.
Jun 13 15:57:42 ####### systemd-journald[6532]: System Journal (/var/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 48.0M, max 900.0M, 851.9M free.
Jun 13 16:20:10 ####### systemd-journald[6532]: Journal stopped
-- Reboot --
Jun 14 13:06:17 ####### systemd-journald[2020]: Journal stopped
Jun 14 13:06:17 ####### systemd-journald[333498]: Journal started
Jun 14 13:06:17 ####### systemd-journald[333498]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 37.1M, max 37.1M, 0B free.
Jun 14 13:06:17 ####### systemd-journald[333498]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024 is 3.509167s for 26919 entries.
Jun 14 13:06:17 ####### systemd-journald[333498]: System Journal (/var/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 82.0M, max 900.0M, 817.9M free.
Jun 14 13:06:30 ####### systemd-journald[333498]: Journal stopped
Jun 14 13:06:30 ####### systemd-journald[333538]: Journal started
Jun 14 13:06:30 ####### systemd-journald[333538]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 4.6M, max 37.1M, 32.4M free.
Jun 14 13:06:30 ####### systemd-journald[333538]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024 is 4.822ms for 15 entries.
Jun 14 13:06:30 ####### systemd-journald[333538]: System Journal (/var/log/journal/e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024) is 82.0M, max 900.0M, 817.9M free.
Jun 14 14:22:28 ####### systemd-journald[333538]: Journal stopped
```

We use a symlink so that logs can be stored on a hard drive instead of the ssd to save on read/writes:

```
pi@######:~$ ls -ltr /var/log
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root syslog 17 Jan 10 06:57 /var/log -> /mnt/usbdrive/log
```

machine-id is populated and does not change on boot:

```
pi@######:~$ cat /etc/machine-id
e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024
```

The /etc/systemd/journal.conf file is set up as follows:

```
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
#Compress=yes
#Seal=yes
#SplitMode=uid
#SyncIntervalSec=5m
#RateLimitIntervalSec=30s
#RateLimitBurst=10000
SystemMaxUse=900M
#SystemKeepFree=
SystemMaxFileSize=50M
#SystemMaxFiles=100
#RuntimeMaxUse=
#RuntimeKeepFree=
#RuntimeMaxFileSize=
#RuntimeMaxFiles=100
#MaxRetentionSec=
#MaxFileSec=1month
ForwardToSyslog=no
#ForwardToKMsg=no
#ForwardToConsole=no
#ForwardToWall=yes
#TTYPath=/dev/console
#MaxLevelStore=debug
#MaxLevelSyslog=debug
#MaxLevelKMsg=notice
#MaxLevelConsole=info
#MaxLevelWall=emerg
#LineMax=48K
#ReadKMsg=yes
```

/var/log/journal permissions:

```
pi@######:/var/log$ ls -ltr journal
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root systemd-journal 4096 Jun 14 13:06 e00bd6223a7245d0aa6e19e0ab12a024
pi@######:~$ ls -ld /var/log/journal/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root systemd-journal 4096 Jun 13 12:16 /var/log/journal/
```

Docker versions:

```
pi@######:~$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~20.04.2
pi@######:~$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.25.0,
```

Docker journald driver in docker-compose.yml

```
    logging:
      driver: journald
      options:
        tag: "########"
```

The hardware platform is an Odroid HC4 (pi user is just a legacy thing)
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

kernel version:

```
pi@#######:~$ uname -r
4.9.277-83
```